# Eclipse RCP ,why perspective bar not appear?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I called such method in WorkbenchWindowAdvisor's postWindowOpen method

windowConfigurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(true);

but perspective bar stills not show itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling it from preWindowOpen().

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean your workspace of your running product. These kind of preferences are saved and persisted in the workbenchlayout and are loaded from there instead from your code.